# Faster speed: nested for loops or successive for loops?

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop, nested

Which is faster, successive for loops or a bunch of nested ones, for example, 3 successive for loops or 3 nested for loops? Will one always be faster than the other?

Comment: Nested loops will be slower than successive loop of the same length.

Comment: You are comparing different semantics, that doesn't make sense. It's like wondering if sorting a list will be always be faster than render a triangle with OpenGL.

Comment: If they're nested, they're multiplicative. What do you mean OP?

Comment: pleae chech this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be help you to raise your content quality

Comment: why don't you test it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Successive loops will tend to be faster as long as there aren't too many.

In a nested loop, for every increase in an argument n you could have an increase in time that is n squared.  With successive loops any increase in n results in a linear change in execution time.