# Is it possible to improve loop performance or improve completion speed with lapply alternatives

Tags: r, date, for-loop, lapply, posixct

I have a nested `for` loop that is running through every line in an 800,000+ observation `data.frame` called `alltrx`. It checks whether each value in the `Posixct` formatted column `TIME` in `alltrx` is within a date interval created from values in a second `data.frame` called `long`. If the condition is true the loop takes the row number from the "correct" line of which the date interval was obtained from `long` and puts it into a new column `alltrx$Survey`. As far as I can tell it is working, but I tried with a progress bar and only got through 4% in one hour. I would like to ask if anyone has ideas on how to speed this up? I also have `alltrx` as a list of lists where the data is divided up among the lists (in a way that makes sense to my project).

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745590/make-code-fast-execute-replace-for-loops) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106754/faster-speed-nested-for-loops-or-successive-for-loops) but it didn't seem to provide much chance of improving the speed the second being not much help at all...

....see my code below

```
for (i in 1:nrow(alltrx)){ 
  for (j in 1:nrow(long)) {
    if(alltrx$TIME2[i] %within% 
       (interval(ymd(long$V2[j]), ymd(long$V1[j])))){alltrx$Survey[i]<-row.name(long[j])}
  }
}
```

I am interested in improving either my loop code or other coding alternatives that may have better performance such as `lapply` thanks for any and all help. I haven't provided a data set as it doesn't seem necessary but can do so if someone points out the importance of having it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this process was made significantly faster (5 minutes compared to ~24 hours) by processing the large data frame as a series of lists which (I think) allows multiple processes to occur at once. Where the date interval was concerned `fuzzyjoin::left_fuzzy_join()` was useful in outlining the conditions where the `match_fun` argument allows you to determine the conditional relationship with each 2 variables selected in the `by` argument. Hope someone out there finds this interesting or even useful :p

To complete the example below is the running command from my script. Note: the original `alltrx` file was divided into a list of `data.frame`s called `alltrx.list`

```
 fuzz.join <- lapply(alltrx.list, function(x){
      fuzzy_left_join(x, long, by = c("TIME" = "V1", "TIME" = "V2")
    , match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))
    })
```